# Can we embed the geo location coordinates inside another array or does it have to be at the base of the object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geolocation, mongoose

An example will make the question more clear.

```
var UserSchema =
 mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    uniqueIdentifier: String,
    phoneNumber: String,
    gpsModuleId: String,
    userType: String,
    groupInfo: {
        groupDisclosureFlag: Boolean,
        groupContacts: []
    },
    tenantId: String,
    notificationStore: String,
    latLongInfo: [{
        loc: {
        type: String,
        coordinates: []
        },
        date: Date,
        isAnchor: Boolean,
        isPOT: Boolean,
        isStopTracking: Boolean,
        signalType: String
    }]
});
```

This is my mongoose schema. Can I query using the mongodb default geo location queries with the same hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally acceptable, and will work fine with the `2dsphere` index.  You can check out https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8907. MongoDB 2.6.X will release with support for [Geometry Collections](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#geometry-collection), which are a native GeoJSON type similar to what you are doing here, but there shouldn't be any significant difference (performance or flexibility wise) between the two.

Comment: the comments below the jira say that the issue might not be resolved. can you please confirm? Thanks.

Comment: It won't be backported to a 2.4.X release, but will be included in 2.6 and forward.  As I said though, there's no need to wait, embedding a list of docs works fine.  Just `ensureIndex({'latLongInfo.loc', '2dsphere'}), and you will be golden.